# How to pass custom quote id while placing order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, onepage-checkout, quote, custom-quote

I have created a functionality to replace default checkout cart quote values by my custom quote values, and it is working fine for me.
But, when I am placing an order, order is taking checkout cart quote id, and the values are not same as my Custom quote values.
Please guide me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: On Order Call the event and Update from Observer your custom Quote id @Ronak Parmar.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, I have used

> controller_action_predispatch

observer method and written controller name condition as per my requirement. Here is the code.

> File Path > - app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="modulename" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\ObserverName" />
    </event> 
</config>
```

> File Path > - app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/ObserverName.php

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Description of ObserverName
 *
 * @author 
 */
class ObserverName implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $redirect;
    protected $onePage;
    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect        [description]
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory                 $quoteFactory    [description]
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage              $onePage         [description]
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface        $quoteRepository [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage $onePage,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->redirect        = $redirect;
        $this->quoteFactory    = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->onePage         = $onePage;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $event   = $observer->getEvent();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();

        if (($redirectUrl == 'your_site_url' && $request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_index_index')) {

            $quote // Here you have to get your Custom Quote.
            $quote->setIsActive(1);
            $quote->getBillingAddress();
            $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($custom_QuoteId); // $custom_QuoteId = You have to Pass here your custom quote id.
            $this->onePage->setQuote($quote);
        }
    }
}
```